# Identify Maxima and Minima for a 3 variable equation with conditions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

I would like to find the points at which $x$ is maximum for any $y$ and $z$, $y$ is maximum for any $x$ and $z$, and $z$ is maximum for any $x$ and $y$.

I have the following 3 variable ($x$, $y$ and $z$) system of equations;
$$ c = \frac{(x-m)^2}{m} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{k} + \frac{(z-j)^2}{j}$$
and;
$$ x+y+z=m+k+j=N$$

where $c$, $m$, $k$, $j$ and $N$ are all *postive* constants. Furthermore, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are constrained to *positive* values. I have an inkling that partial derivatives can produce an answer but i can't get there. Keep in mind that 'novice' would be a generous description of my expertise.

**Edit :** Working solution as per @Avi 's comment i am attempting to use Lagrange multiplier to solve this problem;
$$ F(x,y,z) = \frac{(x-m)^2}{m} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{k} + \frac{(z-j)^2}{j} -c$$

$$ F(x,y,z) = \frac{(x^2-2mx+m^2)}{m} + \frac{(y^2-2ky+k^2)}{k} + \frac{(z^2-2jz+j^2)}{j} -c$$
$$ F(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2}{m} + \frac{y^2}{k} + \frac{z^2}{j} - 2x-2y-2z -c + m+k+j$$

So then considering my Lagrange multiplier to be;
$$F(\lambda) = x+y+z-N$$

I have; 
$$ F(x,y,z,\lambda) = \frac{x^2}{m} + \frac{y^2}{k} + \frac{z^2}{j} - 2x-2y-2z -c + m+k+j + \lambda(x+y+z-N)$$

Setting partial derivatives to $0$, i get;
$$F_x=\frac{2x}{m}-2+\lambda=0$$
$$F_y=\frac{2y}{k}-2+\lambda=0$$
$$F_x=\frac{2z}{j}-2+\lambda=0$$
$$F_\lambda = x+y+z-N=0$$

Solving the first 3 equations for $x$,$y$ and $z$, i get;
$$x=m-\frac{m\lambda}{2}$$
$$y=k-\frac{k\lambda}{2}$$
$$z=j-\frac{j\lambda}{2}$$
and plugging these into $F_\lambda$ above;

$$F_\lambda=m+k+j - N- \frac{\lambda(m+k+j)}{2}=0$$
solving for $\lambda$ i get;
$$\lambda=\frac{2(m+k+j-N)}{m+k+j}$$ and since $m+k+j=N$; then $\lambda=0$
and;
$$x=m, y=k, z=j$$

So the function $F(x,y,z)$ is at a minimum when $x=m, y=k, z=j$, which makes perfect sense. **But what about maxima?**

Comment: Are $m,k,j$ positive?

Comment: yes all variables and constants are positive.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multipliers? If so, then you are done.

Comment: no i don't, but i will certainly investigate them further and respond if i'm still having trouble